# jQuery : how to intersect two data-attribute selector queries

Tags: jquery

I've got some DOM elements with attributes data-foo and data-bar.

Is there an elegant way to return only those elements that match on both attributes ?

At the moment I'm just using a filter, but maybe there's a better way

```
var result = $('[data-foo="aaa"]').filter('[data-bar="bbb"]');
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just join both selectors together

```
var result = $('[data-foo="aaa"][data-bar="bbb"]');
```

Answer (score 2):

Just tack it on after the first one:

```
$('[data-foo="aaa"][data-bar="bbb"]');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NaHwb/